# ReactJS Memo - dynamic For Loop container with dynamic memoized Children, how to only re-render a single child rather than everything

Tags: reactjs, react-native, memoization, react-functional-component

I have dynamic elements being loaded, and wanted to implement slider / pagerView so I am utilizing react-native-pager-view, which essentially requires container 'views' with specific keys for each 'page'.

From what I presently had was just memoized 'elements', and through API means we receive new elementsArray, and from there any updates received would just only update a single element member, not all of them.

However, to implement PagerView, we need to have containers and on these containers I'm adding the memoized children elements. The idea is to have dynamic sliding 'pages' with maximum four elements.

This however does not work as expected and once elementsArray is updated, ALL of the container and children are re-rendered.

Following is a sample test code:

**PagesElements.js:**

```
export default memo(({ elementsArray }) => {
    const Element = (element, index) => {
        return <MemoElement key={element.id} />;
    };
    const toggleDirectMap = false;
    const lastElement = elementsArray.length;
    const max = 4;
    const ElementViewPageMapper = () => {
        let cI = 0;
        let viewArray = [];
        for(let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(lastElement / max); i++) {
            let membersArray = [];
            for(let j = cI; j < max * i && j < lastElement; j++, cI++) {
                membersArray.push(Element(elementsArray[j], j));
            }
            viewArray.push(<View key={i} collapsable={false}>
                {membersArray}
            </View>);
        }
        return (<>
            <PagerView>
                {viewArray}
            </PagerView>
        </>);
    };
    if(!toggleDirectMap) return <ElementViewPageMapper />;
    return (<>
        {elementsArray.map((e, index) => {
            return Element(e, index);
        })}
    </>);
});
```

Notice that on PagesElements.js; there's a toggleDirectMap const I've made, if it's true; then utilizing the direct elementsArray.map function makes the memo work and only the updated element is re-rendered, however on false, which is the case for PagerView, even if I add memo() at container view [viewArray], it still acts the same and re-renders EVERYTHING.

So my question is, how abouts do I make it so there are multiple dynamic page containers which each can have max four children elements, and once we receive any update to only update that specific child element and not the whole thing?

Any suggestion or insight would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

You have made the code very complicated, I can already see several problems. The first is to use the key prop not in direct rendering, but inside the component - this will NOT work as you would expect.
Also, using a loop inside the render is also a bad idea, since this logic will run on EVERY render, which can lead to side effects, and in general, it is not the most optimized approach to do some calculations inside the render.
A small example of how it could be:

```
const Element = memo(({ item }) => {
  return <h1>{item.title}</h1>;
});

const Pager = memo(({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Pager</h2>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <Element key={item.title} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});

const DATA = Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, i) => ({
  title: `Item ${i + 1}`
}));

const CHUNK_SIZE = 4;

export default function App() {
  const elements = useMemo(() => {
    return Array.from({
      length: Math.ceil(DATA.length / CHUNK_SIZE)
    }).map((_, i) => DATA.slice(i * CHUNK_SIZE, i * CHUNK_SIZE + CHUNK_SIZE));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {elements.map((item, i) => (
        <Pager key={i} data={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The fact that the example is based on a regular react, it doesn’t matter because we need to understand the concept

Despite the fact that it will work in principle, and I don’t think that you will have problems with optimization, since we cannot avoid rendering when changing the element, since the reference to the array will change anyway.

The only problem that we have solved here is the separation on the pager.

If we want only the component itself to be rendered when it changes. It probably makes sense to use a context or state manager (redux for example) and inside the component itself we will subscribe to data changes.
That is, we will have, for example, the same array only from id elements.
And inside the Element component, we will subscribe to changes and update from within the component. And then if the ID array does not change the order or the number of elements, everything will work, but if the order changes, then the rerender cannot be avoided.

Please tell us in more detail for what purposes you need this behavior (maybe a repeated renderer is not so scary? In my opinion this should not cause any more problems, with the correct use of the keys, we will not have expensive component unmounts-mounts). It is also useful to know which stack is being used to store the data in order to determine the most suitable approach (Context may be redundant)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough feedback, much appreciated!

I see, I implemented this and it seems to have resolved the separation on the pager as stated, now the elements are still re-rendering. The library expects only "View" with key, though using with 1 level above <Pager> seems to be resolve it, the elements not so much.

The Element Array has unique IDs and the order doesn't change, the purpose is that these elements have videos [RTCView] and their specific toggling is causing all elements to re-render and cause severe performance issues as well as botchy interface on any change.